# Body free fall calculation of the time durance as a direct derivation by time (non-relativistic)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, free-fall

Let's assume a body in free fall during 16 meters without resistance and I'd like to directly calculate the time of this fall.

Sure, one could painfully calculate:

$v^2 = 16 m·9.81 \frac{m}{s^2}$

$v = √(156.96 \frac{m^2}{s^2}) = 12.528 \frac{m}{s}$

$v_{average} = \frac{1}{2}·12.528 \frac{m}{s} = 6.264 \frac{m}{s}$

$t = \frac{16 m}{6.264 \frac{m}{s}} = 2.554 s$

But when trying to get a formula directly from $a = \frac{s}{t^2} [\frac{m}{s^2}]$, I'm only getting $t = √\frac{s}{a} = √\frac{16 m}{9.81\frac{m}{s^2}} = 1.277 s$, which is meaningless because it uses the current velocity and not the average velocity, or am I wrong on this? If yes, why?

If I'm right, it's likely about using the correct differential of $t^2 dt = \frac{s}{a}dt$, but how to get it?

Comment: $a=s/t$ is plain wrong. The 2nd equation of motion for constant acceleration is $s=ut+\dfrac{1}{2}at^2$, which reduces to $s=\dfrac{1}{2}at^2$ for a release from rest.

Comment: But I wrote $a = \frac{s}{t^2}$...still I am going to have a look into that equation ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I made a typo in your equation. Time period, t would become $t=\sqrt{2s/a}$

Comment: And ah, even your first equation is incorrect. You missed a factor of 2 in both your equations. And since you had the velocity, you could use v=at to get the time..

Comment: So the correct answer would be $t = √\frac{2s}{a} = 1.806s$, right?

Comment: My calculator says 1.807 (approx), but yes, that is the correct expression at least. And v=u+at gives v=at for release from rest. Thus, t=v/a

Comment: But how do you mean "use v=at" to get the time?

Comment: v=u+at gives v=at for release from rest. Thus, t=v/a.

Comment: But $\frac{12.528m/s}{9.81 m/s^2} = 1.277s$...so how do you mean this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140552/discussion-between-sk-the-learner-and-marcus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fundamental definitions $v=\mathrm ds/\mathrm dt$ and $a=\mathrm dv/\mathrm dt$:

$$v=\int a \, \mathrm dt =at+v_0 \Leftrightarrow\\
s=\int v \, \mathrm dt =\int at+v_0\, \mathrm dt\Leftrightarrow \\
s=s_0+v_0t+\frac12at^2$$

As you can see, your formula $a=s/t^2$ is incorrect, even in the case of zero start position and zero initial speed. Use the above formula instead in general (or one of the other similarly derived kinematic equations). I would avoid using average speeds in general unless I have a clear overview.

Comment: Brief but nice answer, where there is most beauty in brevity...thanks.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but we cannot always derive the equations, specially for example, in an exam. So the OP should memorize some of the fundamental formulae after they have the derivation

Comment: @SK-the-Learner: David Bressoud would certainly agree with you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5M2RWtD4EzI&t=1580 ;-)

Comment: @SK-the-Learner Naturally  The four kinematic motion equations are key syllabus to memorise. But first, one must realise if other already memorised methods are incorrect - which was my attempt in this answer

Comment: For sure, agreed @Steeven